# Support queue and outbound numbers

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I've read a bunch of documentation and SO questions, but could not find anything that addresses my issue.

A caller calls into our support number and I need to play a system status message for the user. That part works fine. Then I need to play hold music for the caller while ringing through a list of support numbers. The list of phone numbers is not static and will change as users login and out. I've got the call enqueued and the hold music playing.

My thought was to use the REST api in the callback for the wait music to dial the outbound number, but that doesn't let me set an arbitrary outbound number (I need to set the outbound number to that of the original caller).

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: This sounds like a use case for [Twilio's TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter) which can automatically handle directing calls to agents based on the rules you set. It also maintains the incoming number of the user on hold. Take a look at the docs and let me know what you think.

Comment: So when I create my queue, and add my workers. Is there a way to specify that a worker can never be "busy" even when a call is assigned to it? Use case is we want the incoming call to ring down an internal support queue, but as a last resort the call will be going to a 3rd party support number which manages their own queue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if the user is busy on a call then they won't be able to answer a new call, so why try to dial them?

Comment: I want the last number in the queue to be our offsite support center. They will never be "busy" as its a call center. Because of that, I don't want the worker for that ever going busy. Make sense?

Comment: That does make sense. In this case, I would set that worker up not to answer the call directly, but to [redirect to some TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#redirecting-call) which would make the call onto your 3rd party. That way the worker isn't tied up with an actual call and can always be available to forward calls on.